# Froala 3 and AngularJS does not work when using multiple editors on the same page

Tags: angularjs, froala

I have a page with several Froala editors that are displayed as the user clicks a reply button, similar to the way Gmail displays its reply boxes.

If I display the editor below without setting a custom option, no error occurs.
`<textarea id="editor-{{mail.id}}" froala ng-model="mail.message"></textarea>`

But if used with a generic option set in $scope the following error is displayed, and the editor is only displayed in one item.
`<textarea id="editor-{{mail.id}}" froala="customOptions" ng-model="mail.message"></textarea>`

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property '$$parentForm' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property '$$controls' -> object with constructor 'Array'
    --- index 0 closes the circle
    at Object.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at new E.Bootstrap (froala_editor.pkgd.min.js:7)
    at new $e (froala_editor.pkgd.min.js:7)
    at Object.ctrl.createEditor (angular-froala.js:119)
    at Object.ctrl.init (angular-froala.js:60)
    at Object.link (angular-froala.js:222)
    at angular.js:1390
    at angular.js:11263
    at invokeLinkFn (angular.js:11269)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:10588)
```

This happens if I set a simple option, like setting only my key.

```
$scope.customOptions = {
   key: 'MY-KEY'
};
```

How can I fix this?
Is there any configuration in the options that is missing?

Answer (score 0):

In V3 you need to initialise the froala in this way.

```
var editor = new FroalaEditor('selector', options);
```

JQuery is deprecated externally